# What does "query" mean in SQL Server in "use query governor"

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I am executing a stored procedure containing a number of successive query statements,

Does use query governor apply to each statement executed in the stored procedure, or does it mean a single executed statement - in this case the entire stored procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the answer to my question is that a stored procedure counts as a query in this context;

We have spent some time examining an issue with a stored procedure comprising a number of EXEC'd dml statements, which timed out with "Use Query Governor" selected, according to the value of the number of seconds applicable. Deselecting "Use Query Governor" resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing up some concepts.

The first concept is what is a transaction?  That depends if you are using explicit or [implicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187807.aspx) transactions.

By default, implicit transactions are set on.

If you want to have all the statements either committ or rollback in a stored procedure, you will have to use BEGIN TRANS, COMMIT and/or ROLLBACK statements with error checking in the stored procedure.

Now lets talk about the second concept.  The [resource governor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933866.aspx) is used to limit the amount of resources given to a particular user group.

Basically, a login id is mapped by a classifier function to a workload group and resource pool.  This allows you to put all your users in a low priority group giving them only a small slice of the CPU and MEMORY while your production jobs can be in a high priority group with the LION's share of the resources.

This prevents a typical user from writing a report that has a huge CROSS JOIN and causes a performance issue on the production database.

I hope this clears up the confusion.  If not, please ask exactly what you are looking for.